# Using flags to approve user account

Tags: users, flags

I'm using the flag module to provide my site admins with a simple "Approve Membership" button. When the button is clicked the system automatically associates the new user account with several roles and then changes the accounts status from "Blocked" to "Active.

So far the roles assign perfectly. The problem is that I can't figure out how to switch an account from Blocked to Active using flags.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can switch users from blocked to active upon flagging with the [Rules module](http://drupal.org/project/rules), which integrates with Flag.  Create a rule on the **Event** "User is flagged with approval flag."  Then add the action *Unblock a user*  (under **Users** in the list).

Comment: BAM! That works. Was hoping I could do it all through the flag's configuration. But it works, and that's all the matters.